# Java Executor not working on JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbctemplate, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to execute a query with a jdbcTemplate using an executor object but for some reason the program doesn't go inside the jdbcTemplate.

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_THREADS);
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            inboundJdbcTemplate.query(selectQuery, new RowCallbackHandler() {
                @Override
                public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {//<-instruction pointer never goes to this line
                    try {
                        //buffer.put(buildDataPoint(rs, testPermutationId));
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(0));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                buffer.put(STOPPING_TOKEN);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this stupid bug?

Comment: I suspect that your query does not return results matching SQL criteria

Comment: It does, if I remove the executor part (only the jdbctemplate part) it work like a charm. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Then I suspect your program ends before executor runs your code in new Thread

Comment: Looking at the debugger actually the program goes into the executor until it runs the inboundJdbcTemplate and then the next line it executes is outside the executor code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

I needed a CompletionService in order to make sure that I know when the execution of the JdbcTemplate finishes.

```
{...
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_THREADS);
 CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService (executor);

 completionService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        inboundJdbcTemplate.query(selectQuery, new RowCallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                try {
                    buffer.put(buildDP(rs, Id));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
 }, "Success");

 try{
      Future<String> take1 = completionService.take();
      String s = take1.get();
      if(!"Success".equals(s)) throw new RuntimeException("Error Occured");
 catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        LOG.error(" Could not execute DataExtraction",e);}
 executor.shutdown();
...}
```